# Pulumi: Manipulate connection string during deployment

Tags: azure, pulumi

I'm using Pulumi to deploy several Azure ressources, which works fine.

I'm deploying a TopicAuthorizationRule and I need to manipulate the connection string in order to have it working with an Azure Function Trigger.

```js
const myPolicy = new azure.eventhub.TopicAuthorizationRule(...);

const myPolicyConnectionString = myPolicy.primaryConnectionString.get();

const goodConnectionString = myPolicyConnectionString .substr(0, myPolicyConnectionString .lastIndexOf(';EntityPath'));
```

And I have this error: Cannot call '.get' during update or preview

How can I do this string manipulation in order to set it in AppSettings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection string value is unknown yet at the time of preview, so you can't use it directly. It's contained in a value of type `Output<T>` which is going to be resolved at `update` time.

You can transform the values of `Output<T>` by using `apply` function:

```js
const goodConnectionString = 
    myPolicy.primaryConnectionString.apply(s => s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf(';EntityPath'));
```

which can then be used to assign `AppSettings` (without calling `get` explicitly).